# Fullpage.js wont scroll up after clicking on link href

Tags: fullpage.js

Im using the lastest version of fullpage.js(4.0.10).

I cannot suceed to put it on jsfidle license error block me to use CDN
so I put a really simple part of code here give a copy past it locally will reproduce the problem(and of course link back the fullpage.js and the fullpage.css).

so everything work fine until i click to the "button>a href=here" to go to the slide #here

then I can't scroll up at all I have to scroll all the way down and scroll one more time down to then be able to scroll up upper than the slide id "#here"

I want to be able to after I fire a link to an id element to scroll up.

```
<button type="button"><a href="#here">here</a></button>
<h1>fullPage.js</h1></div>
  <div class="section" id="section1">
    <div class="slide" id="here"><h1>Simple Demo</h1></div>
    <div class="slide"><h1>Only text</h1></div>
    <div class="slide"><h1>And text</h1></div>
    <div class="slide"><h1>And more text</h1></div>
  </div>
  <div class="section" id="section2">
    <h1>No wraps, no extra markup</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="section" id="section3">
    <h1>Just the simplest demo ever</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

[code to run locally](https://codepen.io/cid-wings-the-encoder/pen/poLqbYm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question has been answered [here](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/4443).

I paste:

You can use the `anchors` option to assign a different anchor to each section:

```js
new fullpage('#fullpage', {
    anchors: ['one', 'two', 'here', 'four'],
    
        //your other options...
});
```

This way the `#here` anchor will be linked to the 3rd section.
https://jsfiddle.net/g26adykw/

The other option is just using the fullPage.js JS methods such as `moveTo`.

You can read more about anchors on [the fullPage.js docs](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/docs/#creating-links-to-sections-or-slides).

Comment: I reply to you on ur git so I copy past here in case ppl have the same trouble .
thanks for ur answer but we are still block to scroll up we cannot reach back the section 1 we are stuck to the slide 1 of the section 2

Comment: Answered again in  there